# Is there a way to nag the team when the build is *still* broken after x minutes of waiting?

Tags: email, tfs

Is there a way to configure TFS as follows:

When Build Fails:

- Send an email to the breaker(s) only.
- If build still broken after     minutes, send an email to the team that says "Build is    still broken"
- Repeat ad-nauseum

I know how to do the first part. (Alerts Settings)

Is there a way to make it repeat sending (nag) until the build is fixed?

Comment: You could always use PagerDuty, but that may be overkill

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box, but...

You can configure your alerts to send as text/html/soap. So if you spin up your own web service that does the nagging you can have TFS easily turn the nag of and on...

Answer (score 0):

Set up a continuous integration build. That way, every time someone checks in code, the build will run and fail. Or hopefully, not fail.